# When create csv to import in mysql table need to add empty values for the indexes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, csv

I have a table `MySql` with 4 fields where 3 are also indexes.

I have to import a csv in this table and I would like to know if I should add also empty values for these indexes (empty because, I think, it will replace by mysql with indexes).

For example:

```
 12,"value","example1","ex",1,,,,
```

Or in this way so without empty values?

```
 12,"value","example1","ex",1
```

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english (I'm italian).

Thank a lot in advice!

Comment: Have you tried it on a temporary table? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, indexes are not columns of the table itself.  They are managed by the database.  So you don't need empty values in your insert.

Comment: Thank a lot dan1111 :)